# Question about mutation vs. assignment in Python

Tags: python, copy, variable-assignment, mutation

I am trying to wrap my brain around some foundational behaviors regarding mutation and assignment in Python. Let's take the following:

```
a = [1, 1]
b = [1, 1]
c = a + [b]

c
>>> [1, 1, [1, 1]]
```

Now if I were to assign b to a different list, c would not update. For example:

```
b = [2, 2]
c
>>> [1, 1, [1, 1]]
```

I can sort of make sense of this as b is pointing to a different list object now, where as c is pointing to the object b was originally pointing to.

If I were to just assign an element of b to something else, c would update.

```
b[0] = 2
c
>>> [1, 1, [2, 1]]
```

I think this makes sense because now I am changing the object that b was pointing to rather than pointing b somewhere else.

However, the same behavior doesn't stand for a. When I assign a[0] to 3, I would expect c's first value to change as c is pointing to a, but it doesn't.

```
a[0] = 3
c
>>> [1, 1, [1, 1]]
```

My two questions are:

1. Is my thinking about b's behavior correct in the above examples? If not, how should I adjust my thinking?
2. How come the behavior doesn't hold for a? I assume it's because a is not a list within c whereas b is, but what's the principle that dictates this?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. It is correct. 2. The plus operator creates a new list (copy) from the operand lists but items in the operand lists aren't cloned but kept as they are as references to the very same objects as in the operand lists.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]` makes a new list with all the items for the first and all the items from the second. In this case these are all simple immutable numbers. `[1, 2, 3] + [[4, 5, 6]]` does the same thing, but in this case the item in the second list has a single mutable item, which is added to the new list. So you end up with a new list containing three numbers and a mutable reference to a list (itself containing three numbers).

Comment: You already know everything needed to understand this. `c = a + [b]` means: 1. Make a **new list object** from the syntax `[b]`, which contains one element (the list currently named by `b`). 2. Make a **new list object** from the syntax `a + [b]` (i.e., **concatenating** two lists). `a` contains two elements (the **integer** `1`, twice in a row), and `[b]` contains one element (the **list** `b`). Modifying an element of `b` is reflected in `c` because `c` **actually contains** `b`, which is **modified**. But modifying an element of `a` is simply **replacing** its stored `1` - no effect on `c`.

Comment: In other words: the `c` list **does contain** `b`, but **does not contain** `a` - it contains `a[0]` and `a[1]`, separately. `a[0] = 3` means to modify `a`; that doesn't modify `c`, because `c` doesn't contain it.

Comment: Thank you. The a[0] reference hit home for me and cleared up confusion.